# Iterate HtmlElement in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, loops, browser

I want to get 5 images from a search in google, but i do not know how to do for iterate a htmlelement in Visual Basic and get only 5 images. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.es/search?hl=es&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=775&q=" & "germany")
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & CurElement.GetAttribute("src") & Environment.NewLine
    Next
End Sub
```

This take all the images. How can i do for get 5 images?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it!

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 4
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & PageElements(i).GetAttribute("src") & Environment.NewLine
Next
```